# Flutter: Firebase send me a wrong code in flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase_auth package for verifying phone number, Firebase send code but when I check the validity of code it just show error. when I print code sent it is different with the code that I receive. any one know please help me.
thanks in advance.
here is my code:

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
                      timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
                      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
                      verificationCompleted:
                          (PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                        print(phoneAuthCredential.smsCode);
                        print("complete");
                      },
                      verificationFailed: (e) {
                        print("failed");
                        print(e);
                      },
                      codeSent: (same, a) {
                        print(a);
                        print(same);
                        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                          VerifyScreen.routName,
                          arguments: {
                            'code': a,
                            'customerId': customerId,
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (sa) {
                        print(sa);
                        print("timeout");
                      },
                    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the code received cannot be printed, but it comes in encrypted form verificationId.

When the entered code is verified, you send the code that was entered by the user and the `verificationId` to Firebase to verify it.

If your goal is to be verified automatically without entering the code through this `verificationCompleted`, you can transfer the user automatically.

> **Note:** Provided that the sim card is on the same phone to which the code was sent.

Additional information: If you want the process to be automatic, use the following code:

```
  Future singInPhoneNumber() async {
    FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
      verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async {

          //Automatically verify

                 Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                      VerifyScreen.routName,
                      arguments: {
                        'code': a,
                        'customerId': customerId,
                      },
                    ); 
        debugPrint("Firebase Auth :Auto Verification Completed");
      },
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException error) {
        debugPrint("ERROR Firebase Auth : AuthException : ${error.message}");

        showToast(context, 'Something went wrong, please try again later');
      },
      codeSent: (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) {

        setState(() {
          this.verificationId = verificationId;
        });
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
        return null;
      },
    );
  }
```

If you only want to enter the code manually:

```
AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: codeController.text);

    _auth
        .signInWithCredential(credential)
        .then((value) => {
                      print('The operation completed successfully') 
            })
        .catchError((onError) {
      print(onError.toString());
    });
```